# How do I implement double sum (No Hash - Just using my Array code)?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a two sum problem using eclipse.  I want to use an array and have the program do a standard recursion to see if any of the integers in my array listed below can add together to equal my target sum of 9.

This is the problem I am working through and having trouble implementing my strategy... (Note I have tried multiple interpretations of my coding)

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9, return [0, 1].

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class twoSumArray {

    public twoSumArray(int[] nums, int target) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) 
            {
                if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) 
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer>myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myArray.add(2);
        myArray.add(7);
        myArray.add(11);
        myArray.add(15);
        int target = 9;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = twoSum(myArray,target);
        for(int j : result)
            System.out.print("["+j+","+target+"]");
    }
}
```

Another code I tried...

```
class Solution {
    public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) 
            {
                if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) 
                {
                    return new int[] {i, j};
                }   
            }
        }
        System.out.println(twoSum.Solution);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {2,7,11,15};
        twoSum(nums , 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a time complexity constraint?

Comment: You didn't say what went wrong.   Are you getting incorrect answers? Timing out? Run-time errors? Computer bursts into flames?

Comment: 1) An `ArrayList` is not an array. 2) The `twoSumArray` method is missing a return type. 3) You're missing code inside the `if` statement. 4) The print loop would not produce the type of output specified.

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors in your code. For brevity's sake, I'll post a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve.

Without hashing, you will not get an answer which will run below `O(n^2)`

However, you can get a `O(n^2)` without hashing (Your second solution was actually logically correct, but syntactically incorrect.) For example, why are you printing `System.out.println(twoSum.Solution);`? You call `twoSum(nums , 9);` but you never actually print the result.

```
public class TwoSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] answer = twoSum(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, 4);
        if (answer != null)
            System.out.println("[" + answer[0] + ", " + answer[1] + "]");
    }

    public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target) return new int[]{ i, j };
            }
        }
        // no answer
        return null;
    }
}
```

This solution is generally frowned upon, as it is not the most efficient and is a brute force algorithm. However, it is very simple and doesn't require much thinking to understand.

Comment: I appreciate your honesty.  My desire was to establish a brute force method because I figured it was a great place to start.  First, I wanted to be able to create and explain a logical but inefficient algorithm for interviews so that I could then move into a solution that would be more efficient.  However, I couldn't get the brute force to work; hence my plea.  Thank you, and I will try out your solution now.

Answer (score 0):

You did ask for a recursive solution.  So this works but it does require providing starting indices for `vals` array.

```java
    int[] vals = { 1, 2, 7, 9, 5, 3, 10};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(vals, 0, 1, 15)));

    public static int[] twoSum(int[] v, int n, int m, int target) {
      if (n == v.length) {
         return new int[] { -1, -1
         };
      }
      if (m == v.length) {
         return twoSum(v, n + 1, n + 2, target);
      }
      if (v[n] + v[m] == target) {
         return new int[] { n, m
         };
      }
      return twoSum(v, n, m + 1, target);
    }
```

It returns an array of `[-1,-1]` if the sum is not found.  You could also return an empty array or even `null`.

This should be pretty easy to follow.  It essentially works like two nested loops, incrementing `n` and `m` appropriately and checking the `invariants` to ensure that the indices don't equal the array length.

If, however, you just want a plain old nested loop solution that behaves exactly the same way you can do the following:

```java
   public static int[] twoSum(int[] v, int target) {
      for (int n = 0; n < v.length - 1; n++) {
         for (int m = n + 1; m < v.length; m++) {
            if (v[n] + v[m] == target) {
               return new int[] { n, m
               };
            }
         }
      }
      return new int[] { -1, -1
      };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm late to this discussion - but ***yes*, you *can* solve "two-sum" in linear time *without hashing* (using only a standard array)**, providing that all of your source values are non-negative (and even then, there are clever work-arounds - see the bottom of this answer).

The trick is to declare a boolean array with capacity equal to the largest value in the source array **(caveat)***.  Or, if you want to avoid doing an additional linear-time scan of the array to get its max value, and you don't mind using extra space, just set the capacity to the maximum allowable array capacity (which in the language I am using, C#, is `2147483591`):

```
// Some test input data:
var target = 11;
var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 7, 9, 5, 3, 10 };

// complements array:
var complements = new bool[2147483591];
```

When an array is declared with a capacity, its values will automatically be populated with the default for the given data type, which for a boolean is `false`.

Now it's simply a matter of making a single pass through the source array to see if the element in the `complements` array at position `compIndex` (i.e., `target` minus the current array element) is set to `true`.

If so, add the `(num, compIndex)` tuple to the result set.  Otherwise, set the value in `complements` to `true` for the element at `num`.

Here's the entire function:

```
IEnumerable<(int, int)> TwoSum(int[] arr, int target)
{
    var foundResults = new List<(int, int)>();

    var complements = new bool[2147483591] // or arr.Max() but be careful of overflow;
    foreach (var num in arr)
    {
        var compIndex = target - num;
        if (complements[compIndex])
        {
            foundResults.Add((num, compIndex));
        }
        else
        {
            complements[num] = true;
        }
    }
    return (foundResults.Any() ? foundResults : new[] { (-1, -1) });
}

void Main()
{
    var target = 10;
    var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 7, 9, 5, 3, 10 };
    TwoSum(arr, target);

    // returns [{9, 1},{3, 7}]
}
```

The above C# code can be easily translated into C, Java, JavaScript, etc.

**(caveat)*** If your source array contains a value greater than the maximum capacity for a boolean array, there are ways to work around this (search Google for `BigArray<T>` implementations related to your language of choice).  Likewise, if you must account for negative numbers in your source array, there are creative ways to work around that as well.  For example, make your `complements` array of booleans an array of boolean *2-tuples* instead of scalars (i.e., a value flagging the existence of the positive and negative version of the given number).

*(Note that in real life I would simply use a hash-based solution rather than going through all this trouble.  But I have included this answer just in case you run across this in an interview with a very strict hiring manager :-)).*

Answer (score -1):

you need to do this using gready way you start summing any number sequence which is under the max (result)

every time choose the number which is seems the best choice (best choice means the sum of it to the previous sum is not greater than the needed result)
and brute Force this without repetitions until you get all the possible combinations or use backtracking you get back number of steps when you overflow the result and test other combination options 
this is way faster than simple naive brutal force method wich will have to test
nlog(n) combinations thats unreal if i pass you a large enough array

edit : i have noticed after a comment its adding two numbers not a set then its more simpler first the brute force naive approach is the worst here as in addition operation the positions of numbers in equation doesn't matter so you test every number by the next numbers to its right until N-1 its N*2-1 comparables rather than N^2 in niave force

Comment: *"previous sum"*? The challenge is to find two numbers that sum to given target. Not to find a set of numbers. Not many, just **two**, and the code in the question is already doing that.